# Как задать свойство в CSS для картинки без класса

Tags: css3, html5

Возможно ли задать свойство для HTML картинки , не прописывая 'style' в коде, и не используя класс , как например , для input без класса можно задать свойство приписав в CSS тип input'a ( input[type="тип"] )?

Comment: можно использовать тег img

Comment: img {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img[alt="йа картинко"] {
  border: 5px dotted green;
}

img[src="/img.jpg"] {
  border: 3px dashed blue;
}

img[user="Ooops!"] {
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Можно выбирать так же, как и другие элементы по атрибутам.
В том числе и по пользовательским.
-->
<img src="/img.jpg" alt="">
<img src="" alt="йа картинко">
<img src="" alt="" user="Ooops!">
<!-- 
Или src или alt должны содержать хотя бы один символ.
Если оба эти атрибута будут пусты, то картинка не отобразится.
-->
<img src="" alt="d-_-b" user="Ooops!">
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML код в студию, и получите CSS для вашей задачи)

```css
.containerimg img {border:5px solid red;}
```

```html
<div class="containerimg">
  <img src="" alt="">
 </div>
```